# How can I re-enable touchpad after disabling it via touchpad indicator option

Tags: gnome, touchpad, gnome-shell-extension

By mistake I turned off my laptop track-pad (mouse) in Touchpad indicator option. Is there a way I can re-enable the mouse or at least turn off the touch pad indicator extension so that mouse starts working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting an external mouse and re-enable the option in the same way in reverse as you disable it.