# Mousepad doesn't reactive with touchpad-indicator

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, indicator

I am using `touchpad-indicator` to disable my touchpad when a mouse is plugged in. Until about four weeks ago, it works all fine, now it's only working half-way: When I plug in a mouse, touchpad is deactivated, but when I unplug my mouse, the touchpad *stays deactivated*. Plugging in the mouse again at least results in a notification (saying that my touchpad is deactivated).

I tried reinstalling `touchpad-indicator` but it's still the same. What else can I do?

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168661/how-can-i-re-enable-touchpad-after-disabling-it-via-touchpad-indicator-option The answer there is to "re-enable before unplugging the mouse", though, which is not what you (we) want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two weeks have passed with little activity. I quickly decided that this must be a bug which I filled [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dash/+bug/1547240). Let's hope it helps. As of March 2nd, the status is still undecided.